# Problem with numerical integration.(Is numerical integration reliable?)

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I just want to use numerical integration, and I can not trust the results and  it seems something goes wrong. the problem is as follow :
I have a totally positive two variable function and from elementary high school mathematics, integration over bigger intervals must be greater than smaller intervals, but NIntegration can not realize this fact.
for example :

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}]
```

and the answer is 42.4266

but when I integrate over smaller intervals

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

and the answer is 209.479.

How can I trust to the mathematica, and what to do to fix the problem.
thanks

Comment: In both cases `NIntegrate` gives error messages, you didn't   mention.

Comment: Try it with `{y, -200, x, 200}`.

Comment: You can never "trust" any calculation done using machine precision since there is no attempt to track and control precision. At a minimum, use arbitrary-precision by specifying a `WorkingPrecision`. Even then, you need to proceed with caution.

Comment: It is always a good practice to first plot the integrand and look where the major contributions to the integral are. Then you can force NIntegrate to divide integration area into some with high contribution and some with low like @MichealE2 proposed or even better like `NIntegrate[
 Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, x - 3, x + 3, 200}] `  to get  `707.967 ` very close to the analytical `707.982 `

Comment: @Akku14, Dear Akku14,  Can you please tell me about y-interval.  why do you divide it in that manner?  and how to divide, when I have z-interval too. For example,  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}. I see it works,  but I don't know why.  I saw mathematics helps,  but I didn't find that manner.  Can you please tell me about it's philosophy?

Comment: @MichaelE2, Can you please tell me about y-interval, I see it works, but I don't know why. why do you use that partitioning? how that works?

Comment: `{y, -200, x, 200}` means the integration will be broken up at `y == x`, where the Exp has a maximum `Exp[-(x-y)^2] == 1`. Akku14’s breaking up the region just before and after the maximum is more reliable in general. The trouble is with error estimation. When the function is nearly flat almost everywhere, then discrete sampling will probably lead to a very small error estimate unless some sample points land in a region where the function varies rapidly. By dividing the region into subregions where the function changes a lot, the error estimates will be greater and NIntegrate will work harder.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the numerical integration strategy from the default "GlobalAdaptive" to "LocalAdaptive" gives the expected behavior (and results much closer to the expected ones):

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
(* 352.491 *)

NIntegrate[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] 
(* 707.982 *)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I hope it works for more complicated integrals which I have not  analytic form of them.

Comment: You are welcome! It *should* work; look out however for warnings from Mathematica, that are in general quite reliable in signalling pathologies of your integral

Comment: @Arian: Would you feel like accepting the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Although I got negative votes for my (elementary) question,  but your answer was helpful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First look at the function you want to integrate

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

The plot shows integral must depend on the range of integration!
That's why you cannot expect unique solution.

Comment: integral obviously depend on range of  integration, my question was that why integration over bigger interval is smaller than smaller interval. as is shown in figure, our function is positive everywhere. It was a toy example for my original calculation and for complicated cases I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Adrian The `NIntegrate`- messages gave a hint, you  shouldn't trust the results! Try to increase workingprecision (and decrease your integration range, numerical  `Exp[-100.^2] `  isn't easy to calculate).

Answer (score 0):

This integral can be don analytically. Then you do not have to worry about precision. And you see that the exponential term can be safely neglected.

```
Integrate[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}]
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, it as a gaussian like integral,  it was just a toy example to show my problem. My original integral is so complicated than that,  and there is no analytical solution.

Comment: If your real integrand is also a function of `x-y`, then maybe another parametrization like:`z=x-y` may help.